# Creating vector grid in QGIS for two different polygons without overlapping

Tags: qgis, postgis, vector, qgis-processing, vector-grid

In QGIS I have the data for all the continents except Antarctica. Now I want to create a grid of size 1km * 1km for each country however the problem I am running into is that if I take two neighbouring countries the grids don't align properly as shown in the image below. Both grids and polygons follow the same CRS i.e. EPSG 4326 - WGS 84

[image]

I want to generate the grids in a way that it aligns with the other grids. I am complete beginner when it comes to GIS. I will get rid of the overlapping rectangles later, but I want these lines to align so that when shown on a map, it must look like one grid and not a collection of grids. Any guidance or tips?

Edit 1: I want to generate the whole data for world in the form of grids but I am unable to do so in one go as it always crashes after 2 - 3 days of continuous processing with only 6 -8 % progress. Any suggestions that can help me accomplish that will also be very helpful if this country by country route is too complicated.

Comment: Before anything else, do some math and ask yourself if you *really* want to generate +100 000 000 *Polygons* - and if so, how to work with them after. The ad-hoc gridding of coordinates is extremely cheap in comparison.

Comment: @geozelot Client wants to create plots over the whole world so this is the solution I could come up with my limited knowledge as we have done the same thing for north America only.  however if you can just elaborate a little on your solution or point me towards a article on it I would be really grateful.

Comment: E.g. for an exemplary input *Point* coordinate pair `P[X: -12550035.7, Y: 3798621.8]` (in `EPSG:3857`, which you should ***not*** use) and a *grid cell edge length* `CL=1000 [m]`, the *Point* `P_C[X: Floor(P.X / CL) * CL, Y: Floor(P.Y / CL) * CL]` would be the **bottom left corner** of the grid cell point `P` falls into. No need to check 100M *Polygons* for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one single grid worldwide (be aware: using EPSG:4326, you can't create grids in km, only in degrees. Reproject instead). In a second step, for each country (as you want a separate grid for each country, right?) make a selection based on location: select only grid cells overlapping with the current country.

To do so, you can use <kbd>Menu Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> > <kbd>[Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression)</kbd> with this expression:

```
collect_geometries (overlay_intersects ('grid_layer', $geometry))
```

It creates one multipart geometry for each country, with overlapping cells where two countries border each other.

*Grid (=cells in red) created for France, Spain and Portugal, selected (yellow) cells for France. Darker cells belong to two countries:*
[image]

---

**Edit**

Based on your additional information, be aware of this: As mentioned by @geozelot, creating 1km * 1km grid cells worldwide will simply create too large data to be handled. Either reduce the no. of cells (larger grid cells) or use a more performant computer system.

A workaround could be to first create a worldwide grid with much larger resolution (like 1000 km * 1000 km) and then subdivide it (100 km * 100 km etc.) for certain regions only until you reach the desired grid size. Based on the initial worldwide grid, cells will allign if you create the smaller grids based on the extent of one of these initial cells.

You will need to do this repeatedly for several regions of the earth (countries) separately. You could maybe create a model for ceratin steps to reduce reproducing repeating steps manually.

Comment: creating one single grid is what I want but unfortunately with the computing power at my disposal it just isn't possible tried it three times each time qgis crashed after 2 - 3 days of processing with just 6 - 10% of progress max. This is why I thought if I could break it into countries it might help but then I am unable to solve this alignment issue. Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: It was my error for not mentioning this information in the question so I have added a new edit.

Comment: See my edit in my answer above

Comment: Thank you this is the direction I needed. For now I am marking your suggestion as the solution.  On a side note Client wanted 100m * 100m grid I had to negotiate it to 1 km by 1 km. Thanks again for this prompt response :)

Comment: is it possible to hook qgis up with a powerful ec2 instance so I could get my processing done?

Comment: Not sure, don't now ec2. You might ask this in a separate question here.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use PostGIS - run

```
CREATE TABLE global_grid AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
    grid.i AS cell_x,
    grid.j AS cell_y,
    grid.geom
  FROM
    ST_SquareGrid(
      <CELL_SIZE>,
      ST_Transform(
        'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-180 -90, -180 90, 180 90, 180 -90, -180 -90))',
        <METRIC_UNIT_SRID>
      )
    ) AS grid
);
```

for a *global grid*, or

```
CREATE TABLE country_grid AS (
  SELECT
    cty.id,
    grid.i AS cell_x,
    grid.j AS cell_y,
    grid.geom
  FROM
    <countries_table> AS cty,
    LATERAL ST_SquareGrid(
      <CELL_SIZE>,
      ST_Transform(
        cty.geom,
        <METRIC_UNIT_SRID>
      )
    ) AS grid
);
```

to create aligning *grids over `<countries_table>.geom`*.

---

**Notes:**

- Choosing a `<METRIC_UNIT_SRID>` is trickier than you may think, as there ***cannot*** exists an (equi)rectangular equal area grid covering a spheroidal body precisely - you may want to resolve using a *Cylindrical Equal Area* projection:

  - `EPSG:54034`, *ESRI*'s default *Spheroidal CEA projection*
  - *Behrends* projection via *proj4* string:
    `'+proj=cea +lat_ts=30 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'`
  - *Gall-Peters* projection via *proj4* string:
     `'+proj=cea +lat_ts=44.138 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'`
- Do not create a grid! *Especially* when working with *Point* geometries that have to be referenced to the grid, getting the cell properties from rounding coordinates on-the-fly and lazily creating/storing cell geometries if needed is the much *much* better approach - ***especially*** *especially* if you need the grid reference *mainly* for metric aggregation and sporadic mapping. But also *very generally*!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I will try this out and update my question accordingly.